# `error: service 'BloxPager' did not start. Aborting.`

Tags: logicblox

I install the LogicBlox 3.10, using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
When I try to do `lb-services start`
it prompts me
`error: service 'BloxPager' did not start. Aborting.`

Following in the content in `~/lb_deployment/logs/current/BloxPagerDaemon.log`

```
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR. Shared memory is critically low and will prevent reliable functioning
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR. of the pager daemon. Details follow. 
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR. To force pager daemon start, set "LB_PAGER_FORCE_START" in your environment.
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  There is a problem with your machine configuration that could cause
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  performance or stability problems with large databases.  This machine has
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  8.3 Gb of memory, but only 4.2 Gb of memory is available as free disk
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  space in /dev/shm.  Ideally there would be 5.5 Gb of free space there.
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  There is a simple fix.  (1) By default linux configures /dev/shm to be
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  half the size of physical memory, which is too little for LogicBlox.
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  To increase it, edit (as root) the file /etc/fstab.  On the line for
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  tmpfs, replace the word "defaults" with "size=7g".  This change
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  will take effect on reboot.  (2) If /etc/fstab is already
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  configured properly, there are stale files in /dev/shm that should
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  be removed.  Or, another pager daemon is running (under a different
<2015/11/27 05:33:51.079> ERROR.  *  unix userid) that is using some shared memory
```

In /etc/fstab, the content is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c5a6aaa0-9337-496f-b2d0-eda2d6e6c87e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e8cee437-3b01-4c83-abf6-6cd996e9e21f none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

How should I change it?

Btw, in /dev/shm, I have tried deleting everything other than LB_ubuntu, and it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turns up:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=275653

The thread describes how to alter the default size of /dev/shm when there is not yet an entry in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LB_PAGER_FORCE_START setting?

Adding the following line to your .bashrc will prevent the warning

export LB_PAGER_FORCE_START=""